# FontAwesome not showing in Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, thymeleaf

The following example only shows some hex-like placeholders instead of the correct icons. What might be wrong here, using with `spring-boot` and `thymeleaf`?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/fontawesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/regular.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  </head>

  <body>
        <i class="fa fa-car"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-car" style="font-size:48px;"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-car" style="font-size:60px;color:red;"></i>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Uhm, have you tried placing those inside the body?

Comment: Yes, it does not matter where I place it.

Comment: add all.css file like  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: That works. Could you add this as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include stylesheet all.css

```
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: ... In order to define CSS classes `fa fa-car`.